# Multigroup SEM in lavaan: no variance in covariate in one group, how to proceed?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I try to fit a multigroup SEM in lavaan.

In one of my groups all values for a specific covariate are the same (i.e., the people in group 2 all have the same age), in my group 1 however this covariate (age) varies between individuals. I want to compare coefficients between groups, while controling for age in group 1. (I scale the age in group one as a deviation from the age in group 2).

This seems to not be easily possible, lavaan gives the following error message: "lavaan ERROR: some variables have no variance in group 2: c".

Can someone give me advice on how to implement my intended analysis?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(lavaan)

N<-1000
a<-rnorm(N,0,1)
b<-a*0.5+rnorm(N,0,0.2)
c<-c(rnorm((N/2),0,0.2),rep(0,times=(N/2))) # covariate c has the same value for every case in group 2
group<-rep(c("1","2"),each=(N/2))
dtest<-cbind.data.frame(a,b,c,group)

m<-'a~b+c'
fit<-sem(model=m,data=dtest,group="group")
```

Comment: FYI, this was also posted on the lavaan Google group: https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan/c/xOrS-Pty6l8/m/6iqkT2GIAAAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `lavaan`, you can define different model per group, to exclude the constant from Group 2's model.  The reprex is a little odd in that you simulate `b` as a function of `a`, but then regress `a` on `b`.  But following from that example:

```
mod <- ' group: 1
  a ~ b + c
group: 2
  a ~ b
'
fit <- sem(mod, data = dtest, group = "group")
```

The interpretation of other slopes is still the same (i.e., "For a given age/`c`, a 1-unit increase in `b` is associated with a *slope*-unit increase in `a`").  It just so happens that in one group, everyone in fact has the same given age, so there is no age-related variance to partial out from `a` and `b`.

But in case you use `c` as a moderator in one group, then you should in fact center age in Group 1 at whatever value everyone's age is in Group 2, so that the estimated simple effect of `b` is the same across groups. From your description:

> I scale the age in group one as a deviation from the age in group 2

it sounds like you already do this.

If you want to test whether the effect of your focal predictor (`b`) is the same across groups, just use labels to make the slopes equal (not moderated by group) and compare models.

```
mod0 <- ' group: 1
  a ~ slope*b + c
group: 2
  a ~ slope*b
'
fit0 <- sem(mod0, data = dtest, group = "group")
lavTestLRT(fit, fit0)
```